# adding to label from datatable only last column value shows up

Tags: c#, datatable, label

I am adding to a label dynamically where the value comes from a column in datatable.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

    string answer = row["Answer"].ToString();
    lblcontrol3.text = answer
    div.Controls.Add(lblControl3);
    container.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

However in my label, only the last column value appears. Since these values are answer to the questions, I want all of them to be displayed. My page right now appears as follows. Is there someother way of doing this?

```
1)Question number 1...................
[[labelcontrol3 here]]


2)Question number 2 ...................
[[labelcontrol3 here]]


3)Question number 3....................
[[[[labelcontrol3 here]]
```

Comment: A label can only ever show **one value** - so of course it shows only the last value - each new row that you retrieve **overwrites** the value that was shown on the label before, and in the end, you only have the last value present. If you want to show multiple values, you need to use a listbox, listview, or gridview or something like that

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate new label on each loop:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string answer = row["Answer"].ToString();
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = answer
    div.Controls.Add(lbl); // I think you need to create new div also
    container.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

Otherwise you are using single label which will keep last value assigned.

Comment: wouldnt this keep adding all the answers to each of the label?

Comment: @user3158622 no, each answer will be added to its own label in this case. What type your `div` control has?

Comment: I think the problem is my div, im gonna fix the div first and then use ur solution. Thanks for the help